# Rails attatchment not persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, blob

I have an attachment

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
```

when I create the user and I perform on my seed

```
user = User.create({"name":"pedro})
file = open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/img/user.png")
user.avatar.attach(io: file, filename: "user.png")
the avatar gets attached
```

However, when I try to replicate/update it on my controller:

```
user = User.find(params["id"])
user.avatar.purge
file = open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/img/user.png")
user.avatar.attach(io: file, filename: "user.png")
```

It somehow gets attatched (if I perform a user.avatar.attached? before it returns false and true after I attach it) but the blob doesn't persist/get saved into storage. It somehow only persists with newly created objects.

I've tried looking for questions with a similar issue with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that you are saving it to the database. Try **user.new** instead of user.create. After attaching the file save it.

> user = User.**new**({"name":"pedro})
>
> file = open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/img/user.png")
>
> user.avatar.attach(io: file, filename: "user.png")
>
> **user.save**

it is good practice to add the content type

> user.avatar.attach(io: file, filename: "user.png" , **content_type:
> 'image/png'**)

Edit (Op comment update): you can use **user.save(validate: false)** to skip validations

Comment: Hey, I've tried using user.save but it seems to trigger the model's validation, and I get:        "Friendly is reserved",
"Password can't be blank",
"Password is too short (minimum is 7 characters)", is there any way to just update that one property? some responses say that by using "user.update_attributes" but it's still the same. Thank you :)

Comment: user.save(validate: false)